# Making a formidable form to validate submission only after payment on razorpay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, razorpay, formidable

[NOOB] I am trying to make a form that shows the submit button upon completing the payment on razorpay.. what script to use ? give me step by step approach please.

Comment: What have you tried ?